# Spring Batch - Decrypt before Chunk Read

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch and need some advice on how to proceed....

I have an encrypted file that will need to be decrypted and stored in memory (not to a file).  Once decrypted, I would like to use a chunk reader to process the decrypted file line-by-line using spring batch's chunk reader - processor.

How do I configure a chunk reader / parse  an in-memory stream?

Answer (score 1):

You can do in two steps:

1. Decrypt your file in memory (eg in a `byte[]`) with a [`Tasklet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html)
2. Use the standard `FlatFileItemReader` using, as reader's resource, a newly created resource based on your `byte[]` (like the `ByteArrayResource`) as input (as alternative you can write a custom reader)

Answer (score 1):

As said bellabax in the previous answer, Use a [Tasklet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html) to decrypt your file, and store the decrypted file path on your Job Context :

```
ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
jobExecutionContext.putString("decryptedFilePath", decryptedFilePath);
```

Add your job's decrypted file resource on your job context (don't forget the **job scope**) :

```
<bean id="decryptedFileResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="#{jobExecutionContext['decryptedFilePath']}" />
</bean>
```

Finally use a `Chunk` with as a reader a [FlatFileItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html) pointing on your **decryptedFileResource**, and as a writer a custom writer storing your data in memory.

Hope could help you.

Comment: The requirement to decrypt the file might stem from the fact that security policy demands all at rest files be encrypted. Having an intermediary step that writes the plain text to the file system violates that policy, and therefore won't work in those situations.